# Android NDK compile gmp library

Tags: android-ndk, gmp

How to compile GMP for android ndk as a static or shared library that I can reuse in my projects/

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if GMP use autoconf but if it does then you can try the following:

you will need to follow instruction 
android-ndk-r6/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html
    3/ Invoking the compiler (the easy way)

Assuming that you have defined $NDKROOT to point to root of NDK

```
$NDKROOT/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=$NDKROOT/android_armeabi   

export CC="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/sysroot"
export CXX="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/sysroot"
export AR="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export SYSROOT="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/sysroot"
export PATH="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/bin":$PATH

./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

I was able to compile various open source libs with this recipe. Good luck!

Comment: I needed to add a line for `ranlib` similar to the `ar` line, then it worked perfectly.

Comment: @WillemHengeveld did you manage to compile shared and static libs for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 and x86_64 using this method?