# dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "cblas_sdsdot" referenced by "libgsl.so"

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, gsl

I cross compiled `gsl` for android using `arm-linux-androideabi` compiler following the answer provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285605/android-ndk-compile-gmp-library). I installed the library in `/home/username/AndroidGSL`. I checked the `file` command and it gave me

```
libgsl.so: symbolic link to `libgsl.so.0.14.0'
```

so i did again for `libgsl.so.0.14.0` and got this

```
libgsl.so.0.14.0: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

which means it is compiled properly for `android`. Then i checked `nm` command

```
nm libgsl.so | grep cblas_sdsdot
```

and i found this symbol in the library.

```
U cblas_sdsdot
```

This is how i am loading the libraries.

```
static
{

        System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("gslcblas");
        System.loadLibrary("gsl");

}
```

My Linux is 64 bit and my gradle file looks like this

```
compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.ndksample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: The "U" in the output of nm tells you that the symbol is undefined in that object. Maybe you need to load the cblas libary before the gsl library?

Comment: I did that also but still no luck. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you verify with `nm` that the symbol is present in the used gslcblas library (should show a `T` or a `t` if it is what I assume a function)?

Comment: it's `T`. as it is cblas_sdsdot. So it is present in cblas and gsl is linking that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I replied on your other post also regarding `gsl`. Please follow that procedure. I hope it will help you and you can easily use that `static` lib in your android app.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750943/did-anyone-compiled-gsl-for-androind)

Comment: At least, provide a link to your "reply".