# Did anyone compiled GSL for androind?

Tags: android, arm, gsl

I am trying to compile `gsl` for android but it is giving error. I checked on their website and they said that

It has been reported to compile on the following other platforms,

```
SunOS 4.1.3 & Solaris 2.x (Sparc)
Alpha GNU/Linux, gcc
HP-UX 9/10/11, PA-RISC, gcc/cc
IRIX 6.5, gcc
m68k NeXTSTEP, gcc
Compaq Alpha Tru64 Unix, gcc
FreeBSD, OpenBSD & NetBSD, gcc
Cygwin
Apple Darwin 5.4
Hitachi SR8000 Super Technical Server, cc
```

I want to compile `gsl` for `armeabi`. Did anyone did this before? Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled Successfully. I compiled `static` libraries and then used the `mergelib` to merge `gsl` and `cblas`. It worked perfectly for me. For merging you need to change the `ar` and `ranlib` in the `mergelib` file to `arm-linux-androideabi-ar` and `arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib` respectively. For compiling GSL, follow this method to set the `path`.

```
$NDKROOT/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-21 --install-dir=$NDKROOT/android_armeabi   

export CC="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/sysroot"
export CXX="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/sysroot"
export AR="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export SYSROOT="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/sysroot"
export PATH="$NDKROOT/android_armeabi/bin":$PATH

./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: from where did you download gsl? Also, I had a doubt I wanted to build on android studio because my one c++ library has dependency on it. I am using Windows OS. Can you please help?